# Winsock send call is very slow

Tags: c++, winsock, send

I am making a gameserver (TCP) which might need to handle 3000+ connections.
Currently its having 50 connections and i am already experiencing lags.

I found out that its the winsock send() calls that takes about 100~300ms each to return, which pretty much slow down the whole server as it is a single threaded server.

So far I've thought about two solutions.

1. Redesign my server to create a thread for each client (Is it really stable to create 3000+ threads for 3000 clients?).
2. Find a way to make the send() call to return immediately.

This is my socket init code:

```
int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if(ret != 0) 
{ 
    printf("Winsock failed to start.\n");
    system("pause");
    return; 
}

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(52000);

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sock == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{ 
    printf("Invalid Socket.\n");
    system("pause");
    return; 
}

if(bind(sock, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
{ 
    printf("error");
    return; 
}

if(listen(sock, 5) != 0)
{
    printf("error");
    return;
}
```

Accepting code in a separate thread

```
sockaddr_in from;
int fromlen = sizeof(from);
SOCKET sTmpSocket = accept(ServerSock, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &fromlen);
```

My send function

```
void CClient::SendPacket(BYTE* pPacket, DWORD Len)
{
    DWORD ToSendLen = Len;
    while (ToSendLen)
    {
        int iResult = send(this->ClientSocket, (char*)(pPacket + Len - ToSendLen), ToSendLen, 0);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return;

        ToSendLen -= iResult;
    }
}
```

This is my server thread (incomplete, only relevant part)

```
while (1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT; i++)
    {
        if (Clients[i].bConnected == false)
            continue;

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 0;
        timeout.tv_usec = 1;
        fd_set socketset;
        socketset.fd_count = 1;
        socketset.fd_array[0] = Clients[i].ClientSocket;
        if (select(0, &socketset, 0, 0, &timeout))
        {
            int RecvLen = recv(Clients[i].ClientSocket, (char*)pBuffer, 10000, MSG_PEEK);
            if (RecvLen == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                Clients[i].bConnected = false;
                iNumClients--;
            }
            else if (RecvLen == 0)
            {
                Clients[i].bConnected = false;
                iNumClients--;
            }
            else if (RecvLen > 0)
            {
                // Packet handling here
                recv(Clients[i].ClientSocket, (char*)pBuffer, dwDataLen, MSG_WAITALL);

                //...
            }
        }
    }

    Sleep(1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Thats why games use UDP - although UDP is not guarenteed to be received through as a packet. Also, how big is the data you send?

Comment: You should definetely find a way of making the send call return immediately. 3000 theads will be really expensive for the server. I don't know specifically about winsock so won't answer the question, but in C# it can be done by using async calls.

Comment: The gameserver is using TCP for the room list and important packets.. which is where i get the bottlenecks.
i use UDP for the gameplay for player movements and such already.

Comment: 100-300ms is very suspicious.  Bang in the middle is 200ms - the default nagle algorithm delay.  3000 threads is not, in itself a particularly great number. On a 32-bit system, you would need to keep the stack size to a reasonable level, (ie. no the 1MB default), so as not to exhaust virtual address space.  IOCP and similar technologies do scale better - the blocking calls are made by a kernel threadpool, so eliminating a lot of stacks and ring cycles, and there is at least the potential to avoid data copying since user threads supply buffers for data to be written in directly by the driver.

Answer (score 4):

I would go for [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) ([IO completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx)) which can bring the desired performance and which scales well. Take a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio) which is using [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) under the hood (on windows).

The idea to have 3000 and more threads is very bad and really don't scale (in terms of memory consumption and context switches)!

Comment: I looked about IOCP and all i find about is it helps me detecting socket event rather than doing a for loop.
How does that help the send() call delay?

Comment: IOCP helps to make the send operations asynchronous. See for example [boost::asio::async_write(..)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html)

Answer (score 0):

One thing comes to mind immediately, and that is to use non-blocking sockets and check if the sockets is writable with `select`.

As a side-note, you are using the return value from `select` wrong. It returns `0` on timeout, a positive number if there are sockets ready in any set, and `-1` if there is an error. You do not check for the error. Also, while not needed in the winsock version, the first argument to `select` should really be the highest socket number plus one.

Another point, you are only using `select` for one client at a time, add *all* clients to the set and then do a `select`:

```
fd_set readset;
FD_ZERO(&readset);
SOCKET max_socket = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT; i++)
{
    if (Clients[i].bConnected)
    {
        FD_SET(Clients[i].ClientSocket, &readset);
        max_socket = std::max(max_socket, Clients[i].ClientSocket);
    }
}

int res = select(max_socket + 1, &readset, 0, 0, &timeout);
if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    std::cout << "Error #" << WSAGetLastError() << '\n';
else if (res > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT; i++)
    {
        if (Clients[i].bConnected && FD_ISSET(Clients[i].ClientSocket, &readset))
        {
            // Read from client
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea is to make a send buffer per client, append data to be sent every time on that buffer, then in a separate thread check if the socket is writable before calling a winsock send() for each client?
The winsock send() call wont take 100ms+ if the socket was writable?

Comment: Ohh and that idea is wrong.
fdset can handle up to 64 sockets.

Comment: @user1537941 By default, `fd_set` should be able to contain 1024 sockets. _May_ be increased by `#define FD_SETSIZE` before including `<winsock.h>`.

Comment: @user1537941 I don't know about the timing, but at least doing a single large `send` will be more effective than doing smaller and scattered `send`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider is to have multiple worker threads handling a proportion of the active connections and make this configurable.  For example you could create n threads per core and then experiment with n.

This should give you a lot of the benefits of multi-threading without going to the extreme of one thread per client.

Comment: Yes it would give a boost, but would still block because of the 300ms+ each send call.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only sending small packets, set the the TCP_NODELAY option with setsockopt(), to start with.